# Register SQS as trigger of lambda on deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, aws-sam

I have lambda function and SQS queue. I would like to connect this two thing on deployment automatically. So I have this template.yaml. But somewhere in my config is error, because this doesn't create trigger nor EventSourceMapping. Can you help me? I must be missing something.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Create contract function


Resources:
  CreateContractFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          QUEUE_REQUEST: !ImportValue request:Queue
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      Policies:
      - Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
          - "sqs:SendMessage"
          - "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
          - "sqs:DeleteMessage"
          - "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
          Resource: "*"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            - "lambda:InvokeAsync"
          Resource: "*"
      Events:
        SQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: *arn*
            BatchSize: 10
            MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 30
            Enabled: true

      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: AllAtOnce

Outputs:
  LogFunction:
    Value: !GetAtt CreateFunction.Arn
    Export:
      Name: lambda-create
```

Comment: Have you checked the template definition in the cloudformation console to debug the issue? What does the synthesized template look like? Is the eventsourcemapping resource present there?

Comment: Can you share the error you get? Also is the queue Arn correct? What is your queue policy?

Comment: Seems like your YAML template having a lot of issues like extra spaces because as I know YAML doesn't work if a single extra space is there without any concern.